# Any way to run Docker on VT-x in Windows?

Tags: hyper-v, docker-for-windows, docker

I can't use Hyper-V and VT-x at the same time, and I need my Virtualbox VMs to work for other projects. Is there a way to run Docker on VT-x or is this just not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Docker for Windows requires Microsoft Hyper-V to run. The Docker for Windows installer enables Hyper-V for you, if needed, and restarts your machine. After Hyper-V is enabled, VirtualBox no longer works, but any VirtualBox VM images remain. VirtualBox VMs created with docker-machine (including the default one typically created during Toolbox install) no longer start. These VMs cannot be used side-by-side with Docker for Windows. However, you can still use docker-machine to manage remote VMs.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#what-to-know-before-you-install

If you need to use both Hyper-V and VirtualBox, then you could add another boot entry with disabling Hyper-V and switch back and forth with a reboot.

Not the best but it can work, just make sure to backup (first export command).

```
bcdedit /export filepath\filename
bcdedit /copy {current} /d "Windows 10 No Hyper-V"
bcdedit /set {replace this with guid from previous copy} hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

More detailed examples:

https://mehraban.com.au/2018/04/13/switching-between-virtualbox-and-hyper-v/

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SwitchEasilyBetweenVirtualBoxAndHyperVWithABCDEditBootEntryInWindows81.aspx

Comment: That's unfortunate, thank you for taking the time to answer